# Assertions in kotlin coroutines / callback

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin

Fairly new to kotlin.
I'm testing a http client which executes the calls asynchronously and takes a callback as argument from the caller.

Now, let's assume the caller is a unit test. Asserting INSIDE the callback doesn't work obviously because it runs in some kind of background io thread (using Kluent for asserts, I really like the syntax).

```
client.query(identifier, uiCallback = {
        System.out.println("Found a total of ${it.total} entries with identifier!")
        signal.countDown()
        it.total shouldBe 1
    })
```

I could defer the assert to outside of the callback, but i think that's not very elegant.

In an android context with java i would have done something like "runOnUIThread" (before RX). I also have to use that api in android, so I'll run into that problem anyways.

I must be missing sg. very basic. Is is state of the art to use junit for kotlin anyways or is there a better way to go?

EDIT: That "signal" there is a CountdownLatch to wait for the asynchronous execution.

EDIT 2: Retrofit service definition:

```
@GET("Entity")
fun query(@Query("identifier") identifier: Array<String?> = arrayOfNulls(0),
          @Query("_count") count:Int = 10): Call<ResponseBody>
```

Comment: Which call is suspending here?

Comment: Hmm believe it or not, that is actually a good question. I'm using retrofit's enqueue in the implementation and call the passed callback in retrofit's callback method, so I don't really handle that myself. Without checking, I'd assume retrofit uses some kind of ThreadPoolExecutor...

Comment: I added a stripped version of the retrofit service definition. The actual unittest code is already in the original post. There's not much more to it, really. Also the response type is a retrofit "Call" object so the client can cancel the request. What didn't work so far was trying to run with couroutine dispatchers.main. Prob. should execute instead of enqueue and do the background handling myself.

Comment: Then the code for the `client` type might be missing as well. Also consider using https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the adapter tynn, I'm using that now. It actually works now for  altering ui elements in the callback, the only problem are the unit tests. I have my asserts now outside of the callbacks, I can live with that for now can't spend more time on that issue. Thank you!